# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'> for one column. Works For Another Column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) that looks like this (actually it has around 5k rows, and has another column but with strings):

| monthly | total |
| --- | --- |
| 29.85 | 1889.5 |
| 53.85 | 1840.75 |
| 70.7 | 151.65 |

Iam trying to convert them in to float. I used:
`df['monthly'] = (df.monthly).apply(lambda x: float(x))`

It worked. But when I tried to apply to "total" column", it didn't worked

`df['total'] = (df.total).apply(lambda y: float(y))`

or:
`df['total'].apply(lambda temp2: float(temp2))`

It keep saying: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '

Comment: Consider making the data available. Without it, it's impossible to pinpoint the specific problem; all we can say is there is at least one value that can't be converted to a float. Another option is to rephrase the question to ask for strategies for finding the offending value(s). If there are only 5k rows, you could just loop through the rows manually (`for` loop) so you can see which one causes the error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. You are correct. The original file is a CSV and I only look at the "count" in Ms. Excel and it looked normal. I've just found out that there are missing values on the "total column". When the missing values are removed, problem are solved.